# Access is denied when I call ASMX web service

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-services, asmx

I made a webservice (.asmx) that restarts a Windows service (a Windows service that I wrote "LoggerService"). When I call this service on localhost I have no problem and it works correctly.

But when I call this web service from another computer on the network, I get this exception message:

> Cannot open LoggerServiceservice on computer '.'.
>   Access is denied

In IIS I get everyone and full control permissions. But my problem is not solved. How can I get required permissions so that I can restart the Windows service in my web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the identity of the application pool. The default (network service) will not have access to control services.  To test this you can change the user to local system which has full control over the host system, however in a live environment you should create a user that has only the permissions you need.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Anonymous authentication enabled on the web service?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml in the www folder

crossdomain:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction" />


</cross-domain-policy>
```

cliientaccesspolicy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<access-policy>

  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```